# Jquery, buttons that do the same thing in different divs

Tags: jquery, button, addition

I am creating a questionnaire-creator. My problem is that I just cannot figure out the way to implement similar code to different divs. For the first question everything works fine. The add-answer button adds an answer, but as soon as I add a new question, the similar button stops working. In the comments you see what I have tried.

Thanks for help

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){    
    var quest=2;
    var counter=2;    
      
    $("#addButton").click(function () {        
      if(counter>10){
        alert("Only 10 answers allowed");
        return false;
      }   

      var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

      newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Answer #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
            '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
            '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >'
            );   
      newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
      counter++;
    });
    
    $("#removeButton").click(function () {
     if(counter==2){
          alert("You have to have at least one possible answer available");
          return false;
       }         
     counter--;       
      $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();       
    });        
    
    $("#btn1").click(function () {        
     var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + quest);
     newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
      '<br><label>Question #'+ quest + '</label>' +
           '<input type="text" name="quest' + quest + 
           '" id="quest' + quest + '" value="" placeholder="Insert the question">'+
           
           '<label>Description</label>'+
           '<textarea id="descr+"'+quest+' name="descr"'+quest+' "value="" placeholder="Insert clarifications if needed"></textarea> '+
    
           '<br><label>Select type of question</label>'+
           '<label><input type="radio" name="type'+quest+' " id="a'+quest+'" value="checkbox'+quest+'" <label for="a+'+quest+'"> Multiple choice</label> </label>'
           +'<label><input type="radio" name="type'+quest+' " id="b'+quest+'" value="radio'+quest+'" '+
           '<label for="b+'+quest+'"> One choice </label></label>'+
           '<label> <input type="radio" name="type'+quest+' " id="c'+quest+'" value="text'+quest+'" '+
           '<label for="c+'+quest+'"> Text</label></label>'+
    
           '<div id="TextBoxesGroup'+quest+'"> <div id="TextBoxDiv'+quest+'"> <label>Answer #1 : </label><input type="textbox" id="textbox'+quest+' " </div> </div><input type="button"  value="Add Answer'+quest+' " id="addButton'+quest+'" class="test"> <input type="button" value="Remove Answer'+quest+' " id="removeButton'+quest+' ">'      
    
      );
                
     newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#question");
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
     quest++;
    });
    
    $("input[type='radio']#c").click(function(){
        $("#addButton").prop('disabled',true);
        for (var i =counter; i >= 2; i--) {
          $("#TextBoxDiv"+i).remove();
        }     
    });
    
    $("input[type='radio']#a").click(function(){
       $("#addButton").prop('disabled',false);
      });
        
    $("input[type='radio']#b").click(function(){
       $("#addButton").prop('disabled',false);
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mom">
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Questionnaire Creator</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="nav">
    <p> Insert the questionnaire name here</p>
    <textarea id="info" name="info"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div id="question">
      <label for="name">Question #1<br></label><input type ="text" id="quest1" name="quest" placeholder="Insert the Question">
      <label for="descr">Description<br></label><textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Insert clarifications if needed"></textarea><br>
      <label for="type">Select type of the question<br></label>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="checkbox" id="a"> 
      <label for="a">Multiple choice</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="radio" id="b"> 
      <label for="b">One choice</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="text" id="c"> 
      <label for="c">Text</label><br>

    <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
      <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <label>Answer #1 : </label><input type='textbox' id='textbox1' >
      </div>
    </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type='button' value='Add Answer' id='addButton' class="test">
  <input type='button' value='Remove Answer' id='removeButton' class="test">
  <br>
</div>
<button id="btn1">Add new question</button>
<button id="btn3" type="submit">submit</button>
```

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: You should read about the difference between [`class` and `id`](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/). You need to change from ids to classes if you want to serialize the behavior.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghui well I feel like I need both, because my intention is to access the button through $(".class") (it is called .test in my code) and then check the last digit of the id, that i assign to the newly added class like this <input type="textbox" id="textbox'+quest+' " etc. where quest is incremental. then my plan was to add the new answer at the end of the correct question. I would deeply appreciate clarifications for your answer, because I dont see my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you must be facing the `duplicate` `id` issue. so I have created those events through the `.on` method which is suitable method for `lazy` loaded `dom` elements. I have added classed in your elements.  still there is counter problem, where you are using a global counter variable which is generating `answer #` as per your current counter value which should be the question wise answer count.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var quest = 2;
  var counter = 2;

  $(document).on("click", ".addButton", function() {
    let btn = $(this).attr('data-attr');
    if (counter > 10) {
      alert("Only 10 answers allowed");
      return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.html('<label class="label' + btn + counter + '">Answer #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter +
      '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >'
    );
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup"+btn);
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, "slow");
    counter++;
  });

  $("#removeButton").click(function() {
    if (counter == 2) {
      alert("You have to have at least one possible answer available");
      return false;
    }
    counter--;
    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
  });

  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + quest);
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
      '<br><label>Question #' + quest + '</label>' +
      '<input type="text" name="quest' + quest +
      '" id="quest' + quest + '" value="" placeholder="Insert the question">' +

      '<label>Description</label>' +
      '<textarea id="descr+"' + quest + ' name="descr"' + quest + ' "value="" placeholder="Insert clarifications if needed"></textarea> ' +

      '<br><label>Select type of question</label>' +
      '<label><input type="radio" name="type' + quest + ' " id="a' + quest + '" value="checkbox' + quest + '" <label for="a+' + quest + '"> Multiple choice</label> </label>' +
      '<label><input type="radio" name="type' + quest + ' " id="b' + quest + '" value="radio' + quest + '" ' +
      '<label for="b+' + quest + '"> One choice </label></label>' +
      '<label> <input type="radio" name="type' + quest + ' " id="c' + quest + '" value="text' + quest + '" ' +
      '<label for="c+' + quest + '"> Text</label></label>' +

      '<div id="TextBoxesGroup' + quest + '"> <div id="TextBoxDiv' + quest + '"> <label class="label' + quest + ' ">Answer #1 : </label><input type="textbox" id="textbox' + quest + ' " </div></div><br><br><input type="button"  value="Add Answer' + quest + ' " id="addButton' + quest + '" data-attr="' + quest + '" class="test addButton"> <input type="button" value="Remove Answer' + quest + ' " id="removeButton' + quest + ' ">'

    );

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#question");
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $(document).height()
    }, "slow");
    quest++;
  });

  $("input[type='radio']#c").click(function() {
    $("#addButton").prop('disabled', true);
    for (var i = counter; i >= 2; i--) {
      $("#TextBoxDiv" + i).remove();
    }
  });

  $("input[type='radio']#a").click(function() {
    $("#addButton").prop('disabled', false);
  });

  $("input[type='radio']#b").click(function() {
    $("#addButton").prop('disabled', false);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mom">
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Questionnaire Creator</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="nav">
    <p> Insert the questionnaire name here</p>
    <textarea id="info" name="info"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div id="question">
    <label for="name">Question #1<br></label><input type="text" id="quest1" name="quest" placeholder="Insert the Question">
    <label for="descr">Description<br></label><textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Insert clarifications if needed"></textarea><br>
    <label for="type">Select type of the question<br></label>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="checkbox" id="a">
    <label for="a">Multiple choice</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="radio" id="b">
    <label for="b">One choice</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="text" id="c">
    <label for="c">Text</label><br>

    <div id='TextBoxesGroup1'>
      <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <label>Answer #1 : </label class="label1"><input type='textbox' id='textbox1'>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type='button' value='Add Answer' data-attr="1" id='addButton' class="test addButton">
    <input type='button' value='Remove Answer' id='removeButton' class="test">
    <br>
  </div>
  <button id="btn1">Add new question</button>
  <button id="btn3" type="submit">submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are initializing all of your actions on document load. This is the correct way to do it, but unfortunately it means that any new buttons will not receive the proper actions. I would recommend putting the function that is attached to #addButton in to a function. Then you can add an onclick attribute to your new button at creation time

```
function addButton() {}
$("#addButton").click(addbutton())
<input type="button" value="Add Answer3 " id="addButton3" class="test" onclick="addButton()">
```

In the end though it seems that your overall structure could use a bit of updating. For instance you should use some type of grouping to keep your new questions and answers separate since you are creating them on the fly. For instance id's like "q1-addButton3". You can also make your life a little easier by possibly using jquery templates:

http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates